# Discord.js reaction role doesn't work after restarting

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was trying to create a reaction role command, which assigns roles to members depending on their reaction to a specified `message`. So far everything works, except when I restart the bot. After the restart this `message`, which needs to be reacted to, gets deleted and I have to create a new one.

This is my attempt so far:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const botsettings = require("../botsettings.json");
const guildidDB = require('../models/ModSchema');

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, arg) => {
    const bot = new Discord.Client({partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION"]});

    if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return message.channel.send('**You do not have permission to execute this command!**')
    const channel = message.mentions.channels.first()
    const RedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Red")
    const BlueRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Blue")
    const YellowRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Yellow")
    const GreenRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Green")
    const RedEmoji = ''
    const BlueEmoji = ''
    const YellowEmoji = ''
    const GreenEmoji = ''

    if(!channel) return message.channel.send(`<@${message.author.id}>, **Mention a channel to send the message in!**`)

    const ReactionRoles = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Select a color so your name can be cooler than everyone else's!")
    .addField(`${RedEmoji} - RED`, 'ooooooo red is a nice color')
    .addField(`${BlueEmoji} - BLUE`, 'Blue is ok')
    .addField(`${YellowEmoji} - YELLOW`, 'Yelow is uhhh mehh')
    .addField(`${GreenEmoji} - GREEN`, 'Green is kinda good')
    .setColor('#e42643')
    .setFooter("AYO REACT WITH THE COLOR U WANT")

    let messageEmbed = await channel.send(ReactionRoles);
    messageEmbed.react(RedEmoji)
    messageEmbed.react(BlueEmoji)
    messageEmbed.react(YellowEmoji)
    messageEmbed.react(GreenEmoji)

    bot.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
        if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
        if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
        if (user.bot) return;
        if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

        if (reaction.message.channel.id === "828948095571198004") {
            if (reaction.emoji.name === RedEmoji) {
                console.log("Added role")
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(RedRole)
            }
            if (reaction.emoji.name === BlueEmoji) {
                console.log("Added role")
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(BlueRole)
            }
            if (reaction.emoji.name === YellowEmoji) {
                console.log("Added role")
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(YellowRole)
            }
            if (reaction.emoji.name === GreenEmoji) {
                console.log("Added role")
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(GreenRole)
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }

    });

    bot.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user) => {
        if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
        if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
        if (user.bot) return;
        if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

        if (reaction.message.channel.id === "828948095571198004") {
            if (reaction.emoji.name === RedEmoji) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(RedRole)
            }
            if (reaction.emoji.name === BlueEmoji) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(BlueRole)
            }
            if (reaction.emoji.name === YellowEmoji) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(YellowRole)
            }
            if (reaction.emoji.name === GreenEmoji) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(GreenRole)
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }

    });
}

module.exports.config = {
    name: "selfroles",
    description: "AAAAAAAa",
    usage: "q!selfroles #channel",
    accessableby: "Everyone",
    aliases: ['']
}
```

Does someone recognize the error that causes the deletion of this message?

Comment: Is this your index? If not, you should import the client from there instead rather than creating a new one.

Comment: The `bot.on('messageReactionAdd',` needs to be in your index.js, not in a command file.....